# Stub class instance method to return resolved Promise (using Sinon)

Tags: node.js, express, sinon, es6-promise

I am writing controller unit tests for a Node Express app.

The controller creates an instance of a model class and then calls one of its method that returns a resolved Promise. I need to stub the class constructor and then the method so that it returns a Promise resolved with test data.

**Controller:**

```
const Model = require('../../models/model');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    const instance = new Model(req.body);

    instance.method()
        .then(result => {
            // do something with result
        })
        .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

**Test:**

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');
require('sinon-as-promised');

const Model = require('../../../../server/models/model');

const stubs = {
    model: sinon.stub(Model.prototype, 'method', function () { sinon.stub().resolves('foobar') })
};

const subject = proxyquire('../../../../server/controllers/models/method', {
    '../../models/model': stubs.model
});
```

[Sinon.JS Documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) Stub API says:

`var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);`

> Replaces object.method with a func, wrapped in a spy.

But I get this error when the test code hits `.then` in the controller:

> instance.method(...).then is not a function

Calling `.resolves()` (from [`sinon-as-promised`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised)) directly on the stub gives the `then/catch/finally` methods to the class *instance* rather than to the class *instance method* as required:

`sinon.stub(Model.prototype, 'method').resolves('foobar')`

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have discovered this solution where you make your own fake Model:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');
require('sinon-as-promised');

const methodStub = sinon.stub().resolves('foobar');

const ModelStub = function () {
    this.method = methodStub;
};

const subject = proxyquire('../../../../server/controllers/models/method', {
    '../../models/model': ModelStub
});
```

Credit goes to [Darren Hurley](https://github.com/ironsidevsquincy).

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `sinon.stub().resolves('foobar')` from your stub function.

```
const stubs = {
  model: sinon.stub(Model.prototype, 'method',
    function () { return sinon.stub().resolves('foobar') })
};
```

But you'd probably just be better off returning a native Promise since you aren't keeping a reference to the inner stub:

```
const stubs = {
  model: sinon.stub(Model.prototype, 'method',
    function () { return Promise.resolve('foobar') })
};
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry - the first suggestion still returns `TypeError: instance.method(...).then is not a function` and the second returns `TypeError: instance.method is not a function`.

Comment: Usefully, it turns out that the second of your solutions works for stubbing [static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) (as opposed to methods callable on instances of the class, which I was asking about) - thanks!